# How to test website for ipad without having ipad , in both condition Portrait and landscape?

Tags: css, xhtml, windows-xp, ipad, cross-browser

How to test website compatibility for iPAD without having iPAD , in both condition Portrait and landscape?

### on Windows PC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably have to use a windows browser to fake the browser-agent header.  [This page](http://www.jeffdepascale.com/index.php/general/why-the-ipads-user-agent-string-presents-a-problem/) gives more information as well as the browser agent string.

You could use [Chris Pederick's User Agent Switcher](http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/) in Firefox, but you won't get webkit rendering.  The best option is probably to use the developer tools in Safari and change the browser agent in the Develop menu.

You should also make sure your screen size matches the iPad (1024x768 if I'm not mistaken).  To test landscape, just change the screen size.

What you won't get is multitouch and gesture testing...

What are you actually trying to test?  If it's just a website, that should be sufficient.

Comment: How to enable the Safari debug menu in Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009517/enabling-debug-menu-in-safari-for-windows

Answer (score 7):

also, there is another web-site: http://ipadpeek.com/

but, if you have a special css file for ipad, this site cannot show it. you should change your main css file with ipad specific one...

also, you can rotate your ipad in ipadpeek.com

edit: there is an app for looking your layout on ios device [here](http://thinkvitamin.com/design/awesome-free-tool-for-ios-app-design-and-prototyping/).

Comment: It does not use touch-based scrolling, any other solution?