# Enabling debug menu in Safari for Windows

Tags: debugging, safari

I found plenty of info on this for Safari 3, but things have evidently changed in version 4. I just happened to stumble upon the answer by experimenting, so posting it here for others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For version 4, open Safari from the command prompt with the switch: /enableInternalDebugMenu

e.g. "C:\Program Files\Safari\Safari.exe" /enableInternalDebugMenu

For version 3, the switch is: /enableDebugMenu

Note: You only need to do this once -- Safari will remember the setting.

Answer (score 14):

Checked in Safari 5.1.7 for windows. 
In the top right corner click **Settings** gear and navigate to Preferences>Advanced Tab.
Check "Show Develop menu in menu bar"

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl + "," to open Safari Preferences > Advanced > “Show Develop menu in menu bar. Close and press Alt to see result.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the debugging menu in safari 4 in Windows 7
http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2011/02/enable-debugging-menu-in-safari-4-in.html