# How do you debug javascript in Safari?

Tags: javascript, debugging, macos, safari

How do you debug javascript in Safari on Windows. I've tried google but the only thing that seems to be coming up is Safari Enhancer which is for Mac OS.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

not sure if in Windows is the same, but on the mac version you have a Developer menu ("Develop"), at the mac this menu is shown via the preferences > advanced > show develop menu, and there you can view items such as "Start debugging javascript".

EDIT: just found this: [Enabling debug menu in Safari for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009517/enabling-debug-menu-in-safari-for-windows)

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried using the develop bar?

To enable, go to preferences -> Advanced -> Check show develop menu in the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the page, and click "Inspect Element"

You'll get a pop-up with lots of tabs that looks kinda like firebug -- the console tab is what you want.

Comment: there is no "inspect element" option when i right click on a page. How do i get it shown?