# why I am getting NAN in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am trying get difference of two time in safari browser .It is working fine in chrome .But on safari I am getting **NAN**.when I run application I save today date first time.and on second time I run my application I get the difference of save date and now date .it give correct in chrome .but fail in safari why ?
here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/87mw2ag9/1/

```
var todaydate = new Date();
var datetime = todaydate.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + todaydate.getDate() + "-" + todaydate.getFullYear() + " " + todaydate.getHours() + ":" + todaydate.getMinutes() + ":" + todaydate.getSeconds();

if (localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate") == null || localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate") == '') {
    alert('empty')
    localStorage.setItem("getSinkdate", datetime);
} else {
    var datetimeLocal = window.localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate")
    var d1 = new Date(datetime);
    var d2 = new Date(datetimeLocal);
    alert((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600))
    alert((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600) > 12)
    if ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) /(1000*3600)> 12)
    {
        alert((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime())/ (1000 * 3600)); 
        localStorage.setItem("getSinkdate", datetime);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you try to change `if(window.localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate")==null ||window.localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate")=='')` to just `if(window.localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate"))` to be more correct in checking

Comment: Add `alert(d1); alert(d2);` after `d1`, `d2` definition and post the output

Comment: Where are you getting `NaN`? Did you try to debug and locate the apparent source of the problem (if you don't know how to debug in safari check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5247603/783219))?

Comment: I am using mac not window ..and please run fiddle two times

Comment: Ok... Even in mac you could debug (the initial answer is about mac btw)... Guess what? Your problem is a fault in the logic using wrong operator precedence.

Comment: could you please use fiddle and post your answer

Comment: I will do better. Re think about `(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) /(1000*3600)> 12` you could use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) as reference.

Comment: Also, you should use Brant's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Store your dates as Epoch ( ms from Jan 1 1970 to now). Create your dates for storage/comparison by doing:

```
var datetime = new Date().getTime();
```

When you recall the stored property, you can get the date back from the value by doing:

```
var d1 = new Date(datetime);
```

Your problem is occurring because the date strings you're passing below are invalid:

```
var d1 = new Date(datetime);
var d2 = new Date(datetimeLocal);
```

Comment: could you please use fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change your logic.

```js
"use strict";

var datetime = new Date().getTime();

//  localStorage.removeItem("getSinkdate");

if (localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate") == null || localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate") == '') {

    console.log('empty');
    localStorage.setItem("getSinkdate", datetime);

} else {

    var datetimeLocal = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("getSinkdate"));

    var d1 = new Date(datetime);
    var d2 = new Date(datetimeLocal);
    console.log("datetime: " + d1);
    console.log("datetimelocal: " + d2);

    if ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600) > 12) {
        console.log((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600));
        localStorage.setItem("getSinkdate", datetime);
    }
}
```