# Safari Developer menu - show executed JS on event

Tags: javascript, safari, developer-tools

Is there a way in the Safari Developer menu to show triggered/executed JS functions/code on events on a web page (for instance a button is clicked)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you debug javascript in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247547/how-do-you-debug-javascript-in-safari)

Comment: @esqew this seems to be to not be about general debugging but rather how to show DOM event handlers for an element.

Comment: Correct, not about debugging error but want to see all executed JS for an event, even if successful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it posible, first you have to enable the Inspect Element:

here a tutorial:

1. Choose Safari > Preferences, and click Advanced.
2. At the bottom of the pane, select the “Show Develop menu in menu bar” checkbox.

[image]

then open the Inspect Element and go to the 'Sources' tab

[image]

here you will see the Breakpoints and start play.